# how to pass this (MovieClip) as a parameter?

Tags: actionscript-3, parameters

How can I pass the keyword **this OR an instance name** as a parameter inside a function?

```
function (reference:InstanceName):void // kind of what I want
{
     reference.gotoAndPlay("frameLabel");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify jozzeh's correct answer: your problem is variable scope. The "this" keyword's scope is contained to the owning object - you would need to establish the proper scope of the parent timeline in your function call:

```
function goTo( reference:MovieClip ):void
{
     reference.gotoAndPlay("Start");
}

goTo(this.root); // variable scope of "this" is now at the class level
```

Obviously, we sometimes need parameter initializers, but in this case - a reference to 'this' is going to throw an error. If this is a function that has a changing value, sometimes the focus of which is of its own root, you'd need to handle the initializing logic outside of the method sig.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this being referenced like that...
The 'this' within a function is a reference to the object that initialized the function.

example:

```
var test:String = "testing the test."

test.myfunction();

function myfunction():void{
//this = the variable "test"
this.indexOf('test');
}
```

Also if you want to pass a variabel to a function it should be like this:

```
var test:String = "testing the test."

myfunction(test);

function myfunction(mystring:String):void{

var indexer:Number = mystring.indexOf('test');
}
```